# In Dart on server-side, how to set headers in HttpClient

Tags: http, dart, httprequest, server-side

I am trying to use the Dart HttpClient class (io library / server-side!) and I can not think how to do the EQUIVALENT of the Dart (client-side) call to setRequestHeader.

Specifically I want to set "Content-type" to "application/json"

as per this line (from Client-side):

request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

I'm using the format:

```dart
new HttpClient().postUrl(Uri.parse(url))      
       .then((HttpClientRequest  request)  => request.close())
       .then((HttpClientResponse response) => response.transform(new Utf8Decoder()).listen(_set_dbStats));
```

and when I try to insert:

```dart
.then((HttpClientRequest  request) => request.head("Content-type", "application/json"))
```

I'm informed (in the Dart editor) that head is not a method for request...
(although I see it in the API?!)  Could this be related to it being used
as a POST?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a snippet of working code that evolved from numerous tests and dealing with some issues that were outside the scope of the original question.

Guenter Zoechbauer heroically worked with me off-line to get this dones, I could not find any examples of 1. Server Side, 2. POST  3.  HTTP commands using Headers, this format permits this...

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

String url = "https://whatever.com";
return new http.Client()
   .post(url, headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},
    body: '{"distinct": "users","key": "account","query": {"active":true}}')
   .whenComplete(() => print('completed'))
   .then((http.Response r) => r.body);
}
```

Comment: I'd like to comment to the Dart Engineers on how confusing this can be given that Client and Server are different.  Documents and examples are lagging changes, the API docs seldom include complete examples, and the general nature of working with HTTP is, imho, anything but the clearest.  Use 'head' or 'header'? No, oh? Not to mention that testing can become very time consuming as multiple issues are easily involved.  I truly have seen more than a couple of "Stack Overflow" results along the way :)

Answer (score 1):

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

new http.Client().head(headers will go here)
```

Comment: I went back to the original question post to try and make the problem clearer.  Meanwhile I have tried everything I can think of to set the header and nothing will work.  I thought .headers.set() looked promising but no go either.