# HttpClient & unittest

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-async

New to Dart, unit testing, and asynchronous programming in general. And StackOverflow, for that matter. Trying to build a RESTful server around shelf_route and test it using HttpClient.

My tests work, but they don't exit on their own. Instead, I have to terminate the process manually. I've tried several approaches I found online, but no luck. Can anyone give me a hand? Here's what I'm working with:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'package:toner_track/handlers.dart';
import 'package:toner_track/config.dart';

void main() {
  var server;

  group('Server tests', () {
    var server;

    setUp(() {
      var handler = const shelf.Pipeline().addHandler(router);
      io.serve(handler, HOST, PORT).then((s) {
          server = s;
      });
    });

    tearDown(() {
      server.close();
    });

    test('Invalid URL returns 404', () {
      new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('http://$HOST:$PORT'))
        .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
        .then(expectAsync((HttpClientResponse response) {
          expect(response.statusCode, equals(404));
        }));
    });

    test('GET /printers returns 200', () {
      new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('http://$HOST:$PORT$rootPrintersPath'))
      .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
      .then(expectAsync((HttpClientResponse response) {
        expect(response.statusCode, equals(200));
      }));
    });

    test('POST /printers returns 201', () {
      new HttpClient().postUrl(Uri.parse('http://$HOST:$PORT$rootPrintersPath'))
        .then((HttpClientRequest request) {
          request.write('{"foo": 42}');
          return request.close();
        })
        .then(expectAsync((HttpClientResponse response) {
          expect(response.statusCode, equals(201));
        }));
    });
  });
}
```

**UPDATE:** Decided to abandon HttpClient in favor of the `http` package. Much easier to work with, and my tests now terminate on their own. Clearly I wasn't handling something correctly in my first go-around. Here's what the above code looks like now:

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';
import 'package:shelf/shelf.dart' as shelf;
import 'package:shelf/shelf_io.dart' as io;
import 'package:toner_track/handlers.dart';
import 'package:toner_track/config.dart';

void main() {
  group('Server tests', () {
    var server;

    setUp(() {
      var handler = const shelf.Pipeline().addHandler(router);
      return io.serve(handler, HOST, PORT).then((s) {
        server = s;
      });
    });

    tearDown(() {
      server.close();
    });

    test('Invalid URL returns 404', () {
      http.get('http://$HOST:$PORT').then(expectAsync((response) {
        expect(response.statusCode, equals(404));
      }));
    });

    test('GET /printers returns 200', () {
      http.get('http://$HOST:$PORT$rootPrintersPath').then(expectAsync((response) {
        expect(response.statusCode, equals(200));
      }));
    });

    test('POST /printers returns 201', () {
      http.post('http://$HOST:$PORT$rootPrintersPath', body: {"foo": "42"}).then(expectAsync((response) {
          expect(response.statusCode, equals(201));
      }));
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Does execution reach and execute the `expect` lines? Do you get any output?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, the `expect` statements are evaluated, which is the important thing. But the program continues to run even after all tests run (and pass). I have to terminate the process manually.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You ended up helping indirectly, over [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23987275/3029658).

Comment: Glad I could help. Thanks for posting your solution.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like this is the cause for your issue, but if you start async operation in `setUp` you should return the Future.

```dart
return io.serve(handler, HOST, PORT).then((s) {
      server = s;
```

The unit test framework waits for the future to return before it starts running the tests.

I think the tests should do the same. As far as I remember there was an open bug that for the tests itself it should be sufficient to return the Future when an async operation was started but that it didn't work here like in `setUp`. This was a while ago, so I assume this is fixed.

```dart
test('Invalid URL returns 404', () {
  return new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('http://$HOST:$PORT'))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
    .then(expectAsync((HttpClientResponse response) {
      expect(response.statusCode, equals(404));
    }));
});
```

If this doesn't work

```dart
test('POST / ...


test('Invalid URL returns 404', () {
  var cb = new expectAsync((){});

  new HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('http://$HOST:$PORT'))
    .then((HttpClientRequest request) => request.close())
    .then(expectAsync((HttpClientResponse response) {
      expect(response.statusCode, equals(404));
      cb(); // <== to notify the unit test framework that the async operation is finished
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding setUp. Unfortunately, neither of the other suggestions resolves my never-ending tests.

Comment: I just saw you had the `expectAsync` already in your test but just used a bit different than I did.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following at the start of the main function:
  useGoogle3VMConfiguration();